# Worksheet Change Event - check cells in column for % difference

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to get a Worksheet_Change event to work with the goal of checking if there is a % difference greater than 10% between range G12:42 and range J12:42. I have a calculation in range G12:42, which seems to be causing me some of the headache.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim diffPercent
    'Check that the data is changed between row 12 and 42 and it is even row. eg 12,14,16...42.
    If (Target.Row > 12 And Target.Row < 42) And ((Target.Row Mod 2) = 0) Then  'And _
            '(Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 10) Then

        'Get the values in J ang G columns of that particular row.
        number1 = Range("G" & Target.Row).Value
        number2 = Range("J" & Target.Row).Value

        'Check for presence of both the inputs to calculate difference in percentage.
        If Not chkInputs(number1, number2) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'Calculate the percentage difference.
        diff = number2 - number1
        diffPercent = (diff / number2) * 100

        'Give alert if difference more than 10 percent
        If diffPercent > 10 Then
            MsgBox "Oppps. Your system is not working!"
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Function chkInputs(number1, number2)
chkInputs = False
If IsNumeric(number1) And IsNumeric(number2) Then
    chkInputs = True
End If

End Function
```

The expected result is the triggering of a MsgBox providing a message.

Answer (score 0):

No need to have a separate funciton. You can include it in the main code. Also use `Intersect` to work with the relevant range else the code will trigger if there is a change anywhere in that row range. One more thing. Check if the cell in column J is not `0` else you will get an Overflow error.

You may also want to see [Working with Worksheet_Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

Is this what you are trying (**Untested**)?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim NumA As Variant, NumB As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Set the relevant range
    Set rngToCheck = Union(Range("G12:G42"), Range("J12:J42"))

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngToCheck) Is Nothing Then
        For i = 12 To 42 Step 2 '<~~ Loop through only even rows
            NumA = Range("G" & i).Value
            NumB = Range("J" & i).Value

            If IsNumeric(NumA) And IsNumeric(NumB) And NumB <> 0 Then
                If ((NumA - NumB) / NumB) * 100 > 10 Then
                    MsgBox "Please check the value of Col G and J Cells in row " & i
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: You are a gentleman Siddharth...finally got this to work. Now just need to get Worksheet_Change events going and i am done.